# Map CIS benchmark recommendation to Severity

Tags: cis-framework

I am using CIS benchmark framework to audit my Linux OS, and I have received various pass/fail results. But is there any way to prioritize the fail results ? Is there any severity mapping available for these recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Benchmarks

The CIS benchmarks are designed as an auditing tool, not as a risk assessment tool. The purpose of a benchmark is just that: a measurable point of comparison. The outcome of a CIS benchmark is a pass/fail determination.

This idea works for system configuration because you can set well-known and serviceable configuration sets that meet the most common objectives. While you could make a server do whatever you want, the vast majority of servers have a very narrow use case, and we can set a common configuration benchmark for servers used in these pre-defined ways.

#### Severity

The concept of "Severity", like one has in Vulnerability Management tools, tries to help provide relevance to a negative finding. In VM tools, this is a calculation of the anticipated impact of the finding. A question asking "what's the worst that could happen?"

This question is nuanced when we are talking about an unexpected vulnerability in how something was coded or used. But when talking about the configuration of system that is working as expected, "severity" does not make as much sense. In a configuration, a setting is either what you want or it isn't.

#### Priority

But you end up running a configuration benchmarking tool and you have failures. What should you do to determine:

- if you should accept the failure
- what to fix first

Because we are talking about configuration options, this is not something that you can pre-determine or have someone else figure out for you, unless there are obvious experimental or dangerous settings, or the settings are a form of "hygiene" (password length, permissive defaults, etc.). You obviously rate those settings with a higher priority.

To prioritise your findings, you need to perform a classic **risk assessment**. Only you can know which configurations are necessary for your environment, and only you can analyse the impacts of misuse/abuse of those settings. What would be risky for one environment would be low risk in another.

The benefit of the CIS Benchmarks, even though they seem overkill, is that you can meet the benchmark and know that you have a strong configuration. They are "**Best Case**". They take away the need for doing too much risk assessment for each possible configuration option. To accept a failed finding requires you to do the work the benchmark was designed to save you from. You want to determine a "**Good Case**". And for that, you just need to do the classic work of risk assessment.